# Key code of button "Q" and "F2" coming same

Tags: javascript, keycode

I am bringing a popup when `F2` button is pressed but the problem is when I press `Q` button the popup is coming. My first thought was its the problem with my keyboard, so I tried in different system, the result was same. Then I made a `test code`, just to ensure there is no bug in my code, but it also gives same result. This is my sample code

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
   function giveFocusToRespectiveQuantity(evt) {
       var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
       alert(charCode);
   }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <input type="text" onkeypress="return giveFocusToRespectiveQuantity(event)">
 </body>
</html>
```

As you can see when `F2` and `Q` are pressed the `charcode` is same for both. Why is that?

These links say that key code for `Q` is `81`

1. [Javascript Char Codes (Key Codes)](https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)
2. [KeyboardEvent Value (keyCodes, metaKey, etc)](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/)

Comment: If you stick with `event.which` only, then `F2` gives 0 and `Q` 113

Answer (score 1):

use 'onkeydown' or 'onkeyup' instead. because onkeypress only detects allowed keys, not control keys.

for example:

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="return giveFocusToRespectiveQuantity(event)">
```

returns 113 for F2 and 81 FOR q/Q keys.